# migrate raiserror from SYBASE ASE to ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql, sybase

I am migrating stored procedures to pl/sql blocks, and I have little knowledge in error handling in oracle and nothing in sybase can you help me.

> example: sql SYBASE

```
DELETE table_1
WHERE  N=0

SELECT @myrowcount = @@rowcount, @myerror = @@error, @mystat = @@sqlstatus
if (@myerror <> 0)
begin
     raiserror 40900 "Error: When Generating Exception List #table_1 (error= %1!)", @mystat
     select @cod_err= 1
     return @cod_err
end
```

> Edit: sql oracle i dont know if this is right

```
begin

        DELETE table_1
        WHERE  N=0
        EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
            
            SWV_error := SQLCODE;
   
    end;



   v_mi_error := SWV_error;

   if v_mi_error != 0 then

      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-40900,'Error: When Generating Exception List table_1');

      return;

   end if;
```

Comment: did you even try googling and reading some [documentation](https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/oracle-raise_application_error/)?

Comment: i add my block pl/sql with raise error but i dont know is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which error do you expect for `delete`? It'll either delete some rows, or won't. If table (or column) doesn't exist, code wouldn't even compile so you wouldn't reach runtime error.

Anyway: in Oracle, it looks like this:

```
begin
  delete table_1 where n = 0;
exception
  when others then 
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'Error: ' || sqlerrm);
end;
/
```

`others` is exception which handles various things; you don't really care *which* error it is, as could be any error. Oracle reserved error codes from -20000 to -20999 for us, developers so you have to pick one of these (which means that -40900 won't work).

`sqlerrm` is error message (its description). If you want, you can get its code via `sqlcode`.

---

Example which shows how it actually works (not with delete, though) is query that fetches employee name for non-existent employee number. That raises predefined `no_data_found` error (whose code is -01403) so you could handle it, directly, or - as my previous example shows - use `others`.

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_name varchar2(10);
  3  begin
  4    select ename
  5      into l_name
  6      from emp
  7      where empno = -1;
  8  exception
  9    when others then
 10      raise_application_error(-20000, 'Error: ' || sqlcode ||': '|| sqlerrm);
 11  end;
 12  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Error: 100: ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 10


SQL>
```